# Is there a way to fix this? +how can I save the codes into my computer

Tags: python, input, save

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz4ue.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jHX7.png)

My python version is 2.7.18('cause my computer's window 7) and every single time i try to code with 'input()', it always fails. What can I do?
Plus, there is no saving button in my python. I definitely need a way to save my codes
I really hope to get a quick answer

Answer (score 0):

you should use raw_input() function instead of input() in python 2.

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for answering
but as you can see in the picture, it doesn't work
i guess i should just buy a new computer, with the brand new version python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the print statement have a read through the answer in this post for more details on the print statement in Python 2.7
[Should I use the print statement or function in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191828/should-i-use-the-print-statement-or-function-in-python-2-7)